# YAML-CPP with QTcreator

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, yaml-cpp

i try to use yaml-cpp in cmake with windows 7

I followed the tutorial and build the cmake and get yaml-cpp.dll , yaml-cpp.lib , yaml-cpp.exp

i saved them inside the libs directory in my project.

with

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs -lyaml-cpp
```

i add in in my pro file. The include files are added with

```
INCLUDEPATH +=$$PWD\includes
```

inside this is my yaml-cpp directory with all include files.

On my program I use

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
```

This all is compiling without an error. But when I add

```
    YAML::Node doc;
```

i get the undefiened reference to Yaml::Node ERROR

i dont know what i have forgot to link.

Do you have an idea? thank you for help

Comment: This is a known bug: see https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=216

Comment: hello the bug there is fixed i didnt get any compile error when i compile yaml. The problem is that i have a undefined reference between my source file and the library. How i can tell QT to link the source fill with this lib

Comment: i solved the problem... i used for compiling the library visual studio with an other compiler that was the error i need two times the same compiler